# How to create a file that will exist but won't be readable when you're `root`?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have code like this:

```php
class Service 
{
    public static function loadFile(string $path)
    {
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            //It is fine to do nothing if the file doesn't exist
            return;
        }
        
        if (!is_readable($path)) {
            //But existing file should be readable
            throw new \RuntimeException('File is not readable');
        }
        //something else
    }
}
```

The goal is to test it in PHPUnit. The original idea is to

```php
public function testThrowsExceptionForInaccessibleFile(): void
{
    $path = __DIR__ . '/data/not_readable_file';
    $oldPermissions = fileperms($path);
    chmod($path, 0200); //esentially removing "r"

    $this->expectException(RuntimeException::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage('File is not readable');

    Service::load($path);

    chmod($path, $oldPermissions);
}
```

When I run this code from docker (the user is `root` there), `is_readable` returns true as `root` can read files even without the read permission.

So the question is how to create a file that will exist but won't be readable when you're `root`?

If it's not possible, is there another way to do nothing when the file doesn't exist but catch the case when it's not readable?

Comment: `root` can do everything. It's the super-user / system administrator. It can always do everything. That's the whole purpose of being `root`. If you could deny `root` access to something, you'd have serious problems trying to administer the system. So no you can't do that. I would suggest that the solution is not to run your PHP code as root (no web application should ever be run as root, for security reasons).

Comment: Seems reasonable. Unfortunately, it would be too much to change the docker's user just for this small test, docker is only used in dev. Thank you

Comment: You're going to have trouble running your test, then.

Comment: Got it. Not the most wanted test anyway :)

Comment: You can maybe use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-seteuid.php in that test, but it's probably better to restructure the code, so you can mock relevant functions, and not need to do that (of relevance - by not using static classes (:. Using a singleton pattern can help if you want the convenience of a static interface).